# Fetching a CSRF token to brute force login, but it doesnt return anything - ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, web-scraping, csrf

I'm trying to webscrape to obtain some course data, such as time and location, from college. I'm currently trying to fetch a CSRF token and then using it to login. But when i try to get the htmldata, using some simple unity button, it doesn't return anything. ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length

Could anybody help me out with a potential solution? And possible point out why it doesnt return any html-data?

Thanks for reading

````
    {
        public Text responseText;
        public void Button()
        {
            System.Net.CookieContainer myCookies = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            string mySrc = HttpMethod.Get("https://signon.ruc.dk/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.ruc.dk%2Flogin%2Findex.php", "https://signon.ruc.dk/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.ruc.dk%2Flogin%2Findex.php", ref myCookies);
            string token = GetBetween(mySrc, "name=\"execution\" value=\"" , "=\">");
          //  string username = "XXX";
          //  string password = "XXX";

            string postData = "username=" + "XXX" + "&password=" + "XXX" + "&submit=Sign-on&execution=" + token;
            bool result = HttpMethod.Post("https://signon.ruc.dk/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.ruc.dk%2Flogin%2Findex.php", postData, "https://signon.ruc.dk/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.ruc.dk%2Flogin%2Findex.php", myCookies);
            if (result)
               responseText.text = result.ToString();
            else
                Debug.Log("Invalid!");
        }
        static string GetBetween(string msg, string start, string stop)
        {
            int StartIndex = msg.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
            int StopIndex = msg.IndexOf(stop);
            return msg.Substring(StartIndex, StopIndex - StartIndex);```
````

Comment: Step through your code and validate that `mySrc` contains what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the exception you're seeing is pointing out that the result of `StopIndex - StartIndex` is less than zero. Which could make sense because there's nothing constraining the search for the `stop` substring to be after the end of the `start` substring. Did you mean to say something like:

```
int StopIndex = msg.IndexOf(stop, StartIndex);
```